# Making a popular movies app using GridView, Adapters and Picasso

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make an app where I want my app, on launch, to display a grid of popular movie posters. The movie posters are downloaded from TheMovieDataBase API. I then use Picasso to load the images. For the GridView I am also using a custom adapter. I am not able to understand how to do it. Here is what I have done up till now.
//OLD CODE REMOVED

Please tell me what I have to do so that my app looks like this: [App mock](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/BLcEAGgyiHtsGq8wbilmqj00A2yPFyu1rnrnXl6LrzhdOPK9xJylzzXs-F5iOO6g01wguJVJ9cTXqOerCdmcF3IfjoUx9ySvcIepFMSLq00eWJ-rkede-NlDalD3K5cMZbKYJsc)

This app is a part of the Udacity's Developing in Android course and here is the implementation guide provided by them: [Implementation Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1gtXUu1nzLGWrGfVCD6tEA0YHoYA9UNyT2yByqjJemp8/pub?embedded=true)

EDIT:
As some people have marked my question as "too broad" I re-stating my question. The following code requests movie details from the TMDB api and then displays a grid of the movie names in text. Now I want to display movie posters instead of the names in a grid. The poster path is stored in the moviePosterPath String array. How do I do this?

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayAdapter<String> mMovieAdapter;
    String[] movieId, movieTitle, movieReleaseDate, movieVoteAverage, movieOverview, moviePosterPath;
    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);


        GridView listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_movies);
        mMovieAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                R.layout.item_movies,
                R.id.image_view_movie,
                new ArrayList<String>());
        listView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class);
                String forecast = mMovieAdapter.getItem(i);
                String send = "Overview" + movieOverview[i] + "\n" + "Release Date" + movieReleaseDate[i];
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, send);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.moviefragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            updateMovie();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();
        updateMovie();
    }

    private void updateMovie() {
        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
        movieTask.execute();
    }

    class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String movieJsonStr = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=c20129fdf73b5df3ab44548ad7f73586");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
                return getMovieDataFromJson(movieJsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException j) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "JSON Error", j);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private String[] getMovieDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {
            JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");
            movieId = new String[movieArray.length()];
            movieTitle = new String[movieArray.length()];
            movieReleaseDate = new String[movieArray.length()];
            movieVoteAverage = new String[movieArray.length()];
            movieOverview = new String[movieArray.length()];
            moviePosterPath = new String[movieArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++)
            {
                JSONObject movie = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                movieId[i] = movie.getString("id");
                movieTitle[i] = movie.getString("original_title");
                movieReleaseDate[i] = movie.getString("release_date");
                movieVoteAverage[i] = movie.getString("vote_average");
                movieOverview[i] = movie.getString("overview");
                moviePosterPath[i] = movie.getString("poster_path");
            }
            return movieTitle;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] strings)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(strings);
            mMovieAdapter.clear();
            mMovieAdapter.addAll(strings);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here? What can't you understand?

Comment: @Onheiron: I am not able to understand the flow that my program must have to do the job. I have created a custom adapter, an ImageView in the layout, a GridView layout, and have also got the data from the TMDB API. But I cant figure out how to use Picasso to load the image from the URL fetched out of the output of the API. It would be great if you could tell me how my custom Adapter should be.

Comment: so you run the code and nothing happens? try initialize the Adapter after you actually fill the `moviePosterPath` array at the end of `getMovieDataFromJson`

Comment: I initialized the Adapter as you said at the end of getMovieDataFromJson method and now the app opens a blank screen. Earlier it used to crash.

Comment: update your code so we can see how it looks like now...

Comment: Your doInBackground method needs to returnt the List<String>, which would be a parameter to your onPostExecute method. This will not work unless you do that.

Comment: @jmateo: how do i use the List<String> in onPostExecute method?

Comment: @ShadabKhan Look at my edit. It's untested and just wrote it off the top of my head but it should work

Comment: @jmateo: I ran your code and encountered the following errors: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shadab.moviesapp/com.shadab.moviesapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: @ShadabKhan You should debug it. and see what happens on that line. You;re calling array.length on a null array. My suspicion is that your `JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");` is not getting the data the way you want it to

Answer (score 2):

Edit: [This is definitely not how I would approach this problem, but for simplicity I will answer based on what you already have. This is also not tested but just off the top of my head] There are many ways to accomplish this. The simplest way in my opinion based on your code, is to add a new method to your adapter that clears the current data, and updates it with a new List. I've modified your code to add the replace method, but don't forget to call it when your Asynctask is done and has the new List like this: `mMovieAdapter.replace(listFromtheAsyncTask);` **Also, make your that you only call that in the onPostExecute() method of the Asynctask** read up on the [Asynctask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) if this doesn't sound familiar to you.

```
 public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment { 
    //ArrayAdapter<String> mMovieAdapter; 
    String[] movieId,movieTitle,movieOverview,movieReleaseDate,moviePosterPath,movieVoteAverage;
    public MainActivityFragment() { 
    } 

    MovieAdapter mMovieAdapter;

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        mMovieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity());
        GridView listView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridview_movies);
        listView.setAdapter(mMovieAdapter);
        updateMovie(); 
        return rootView;
    } 

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); 
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present. 
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.moviefragment, menu);
    } 

    @Override 
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
            updateMovie(); 
            return true; 
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 

    private void updateMovie() { 
        FetchMovieTask movieTask = new FetchMovieTask();
        movieTask.execute();
    } 

    class FetchMovieTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMovieTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String movieJsonStr = null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=c20129fdf73b5df3ab44548ad7f73586");

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                movieJsonStr = buffer.toString();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            try {
               return getMovieDataFromJson(movieJsonStr);
            } catch (JSONException j) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "JSON Error", j);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private List<String> getMovieDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr)
                throws JSONException {
            JSONObject movieJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray movieArray = movieJson.getJSONArray("results");
            List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < movieArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject movie = movieArray.getJSONObject(i);
                urls.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getString("poster_path"));
            }
            return urls;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<String> strings) {
        mMovieAdapter.replace(strings);
    }
}

    class MovieAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private final String LOG_TAG = MovieAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        private final Context context;
        private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

        public MovieAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            Collections.addAll(urls, moviePosterPath);
        } 

        @Override 
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new ImageView(context);
            } 
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView;


            String url = getItem(position);

            Log.e(LOG_TAG," URL "+url);

            Picasso.with(context).load(url).into(imageView);

            return convertView;
        } 

        @Override 
        public int getCount() { 
            return urls.size();
        } 

        @Override 
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return urls.get(position);
        } 

        @Override 
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        } 
        public void replace(List<String> urls) {
            this.urls.clear();
            this.urls.addAll(urls);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: It gives the error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shadab.moviesapp/com.shadab.moviesapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Move the updateMovie() method into the onCreateView after the adapter has been initialized. See my edit

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for:                 urls.add("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + movie.getString("poster_path"));